# Why is Django's client.post nesting arg values in lists?

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm unit testing my api with Django like this:

```
result = self.client.post( reverse(path), { "arg1":"value" })
```

Inside the view, I breakpoint.

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def post_arg(request):
    breakpoint()
```

But when I print the POST data, the values have been added to lists.

```
(Pdb) request.POST
{ 'arg1': ['value'] }
```

This example only has one arg, but if I add more they are each added to a list. I don't think this happens when my frontend posts data, so why does it here? And is there a way to not have the values added to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think this happens when my frontend posts data.

The same key can be associated multiple times to a value, for example when you use a checkbox with:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="qux">
```

If you check both checkboxes, it will add `foo=bar&foo=qux` to the request body, so the same key (`foo`) is associated to both `bar` and `qux`.

If you use `request.POST['foo']` it will return the value of the *last* record, so `'qux'`. You can also use `request.POST.getlist('foo')` it will return *all* values for that key in a list, so `['bar', 'qux']`.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense why the client.post would organize data this way. My website is dynamic, and submits data in simple key:val pairs--"application/json". Do you know a way to use client.post to submit a dict of data that would simulate this?